# ODBC link server SQL Server and PG is slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, odbc, linked-server

I am trying to query Postgres database from SQL Server linked by ODBC driver.[linke](https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-a-linked-server-between-sql-server-and-postgresql-using-odbc-drivers/)

The issue is a sample query takes 30 minutes, even if it's one row it takes the same time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [linkedserver].[db].[table].[view]   
  
SELECT * 
FROM [linkedserver].[db].[table].[view] 
WHERE id = 1
```

It takes 30 minutes

- ODBC trace =off
- net bandwidth = unlimited
- SQL Query Waite type on execution = OLE DB
- it is between on-premises and AWS cloud
- where should I look?